# Is it possible to access RS232 with Android?

Tags: android, xamarin, serial-port

I hope someone can help me. A customer wants an android app from me for a special android device which has a real RS232 interface (not an usb converter). I would like to use Xamarin if possible for this task.

Well before I start and the customer orders this device he wants to know if it is possible to access a RS232 from android at all. I have looked through the entire internet and 95% of the pages I found talk about usb2serial converters. and the last pages are confusing to me. Some say it is possible with java, some say you need to built your own kernel because RS232 is not included to android and some say it's not possible at all.

Is here somebody who has experiences in this? Is it possible to access a real RS232 with android? If yes, which API do I need? Can I use System.IO.Ports.SerialPort from Xamerin, which would be my favorite solution?

Unfortunately I can't just test it because the customer won't order the device before he gets an answer from me

Comment: You should contact the manufacturer of the device.

Comment: I think a good option is that your costumer ask to the device's producer if RS232 is accessible with Android